# Erlang/Elixir reraise equivalent for `catch :exit, e ->`?

Tags: erlang, elixir

I'd like to catch and look at an `:exit` catch and decide programatically if I actually wanted to catch it or not.

Is it possible to `reraise` these `:exit` values, like Elixir `reraise` does with normal errors?

```
try do
  ... some code ...
rescue
  e ->
    ...
    reraise e, __STACKTRACE__ # this is fine
  :exit, e ->
    ...
    reraise e, __STACKTRACE__ # what do I write here to preserve both :exit and stack trace?
end
```

- `Process.exit` replaces the stack trace
- `Process.raise` skips `:exit` and replaces stack trace
- `reraise e, __STACKTRACE__` skips `:exit`

```
** (ArgumentError) raise/1 and reraise/2 expect a module name, string or exception as the first argument, got: {:noproc, {GenServer, :call, [:asdf, :woop, 5000]}}
```

Any Erlang/Elixir/beam solution is appreciated. Even an Erlang core solution would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest solution: just use `exit` function:

```
  def foo do
    process_call()
  catch :exit, e ->
    # do some handling here
    exit(e)
  end
```

If you want to keep stacktrace of a process where you called function `foo`, you can modify `e` which has a shape of `{{error, stacktrace_inside_process}, process_call_info}`. Here is a quick example:

```
  def foo do
    process_call()
  catch :exit, {{error, stacktrace_inside_process}, process_call_info} ->
    # do some handling here
    exit({{error, stacktrace_inside_process ++ __STACKTRACE__}, process_call_info})
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

The best inspiration source would be [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) code itself :)

```bash
cd lib/elixir/lib && grep -rni -C 5 catch */**/*.ex

...
task/supervised.ex-369-        try do
task/supervised.ex-370-          reducer.(reply, acc)
task/supervised.ex:371:        catch
task/supervised.ex-372-          kind, reason ->
task/supervised.ex-373-            is_function(next) && next.({:halt, []})
task/supervised.ex-374-            stream_close(config)
task/supervised.ex-375-            :erlang.raise(kind, reason, __STACKTRACE__)
```

That said, [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) core uses [`:erlang.raise/3`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#raise-3) for that, so do we.

---

If you need to catch and reraise `:exit` only, the solution by Matvey would be the one, because [`exit/1`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#exit-1) actually raises `:exit`.